# How can I record a live stream to enable rewinding?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, webrtc, media-player

I want to build a video management system that will support viewing and rewinding live streams.

I am currently using [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/) as my media server and my client application will be implemented in `html`, `css` and `javascript`.

My plan is to use `WebRtc` for the video stream broadcast.

Are there any existing web media players like which support some kind of buffering or recording which will let me rewind the live stream?

Can [videojs](http://videojs.com/), [flowplayer](https://flowplayer.com/), [jwplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/) or other can do that?

Does `RecordRTC` can help?

Comment: You have to support this on the server side.  There isn't enough storage client-side to meaningfully enable rewinding.

Comment: Isn't there a player which supports limiting the buffering time, for example 10 sec, and that way enabling only seeking 10 sec backwards?

Comment: Oh, just 10  seconds? Yeah, you can do far more than that usually with MSE. The problem you have is your desire to use WebRTC for distribution. This severely complicates things.